# How to add posts to a certain page?

Tags: wordpress

I have a category of posts called announcements. How do i show these on my home page?

With a title Recent News?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere in `index.php` put this...

```
<?php
$cat_ID = 1234; //put your category ID here
$my_query = new WP_Query(array("cat"=>$cat_ID));
while($my_query->have_posts){
    $my_query->the_post();
    ?>
    <h3><?php the_title()?></h3>
    <?php the_content()?>
    <?php //etc...?>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: How do you know what the category id is?

Comment: and how do you specifiy what page to put it on?

Comment: You could hard code the category id (find it by looking in the admin panel under Posts->Categories. Edit the category -- the id is in the URL tag_ID=NNN.)

Comment: If you put the code above in the index.php file of your theme it will show up on the home page.

Comment: Im using a premade them and it doesnt have a index.php in the editor

Comment: Is there any where else i could put the code?

Comment: You could make a widget plugin with this code and place it in a sidebar.  If you don't have access to the theme that's all you can do.